# Why does the included code not work in bash?

Tags: bash, unix

```
DOWNLOAD_PATH="sample.ext"
RATE_LIMIT="300K"
mkdir ../$DOWNLOAD_PATH
BASE_COMMAND="screen wget --continue --directory-prefix=../$DOWNLOAD_PATH --tries=2 --input-file=$DOWNLOAD_PATH"
$("${BASE_COMMAND} --limit-rate=${RATE_LIMIT}")
```

This does not work, but throws an error:

```
line 5: screen wget --continue --directory-prefix=../sample.ext --tries=2 --input-file=sample.ext --limit-rate=300K: No such file or directory
```

However, if i do

```
DOWNLOAD_PATH="sample.ext"
RATE_LIMIT="300K"
mkdir ../$DOWNLOAD_PATH
BASE_COMMAND="screen wget --continue --directory-prefix=../$DOWNLOAD_PATH --tries=2 --input-file=$DOWNLOAD_PATH"
COMPLETE_COMMAND="${BASE_COMMAND} --limit-rate=${RATE_LIMIT}"
$($COMPLETE_COMMAND)
```

everything works just fine...
**Why?**

Comment: Why are you putting all that in a variable? See [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: I am using the command in multiple places in my script and want to be able to change it centrally...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you put `"${BASE_COMMAND} --limit-rate=${RATE_LIMIT}"` in quotes, bash interprets it as a single word and tries to find a command with that name. It's looking for a program that literally has the name

```
screen wget --continue --directory-prefix=../sample.ext --tries=2 --input-file=sample.ext --limit-rate=300K
```

spaces and all. Obviously that doesn't exist. The solution is to leave that unquoted, so bash will interpret it as a list of space-separated words and understand that the command itself is just `screen`.

By the way, there's no need to use `$()` either unless you're trying to capture the output of the command. This would be fine:

```
DOWNLOAD_PATH="sample.ext"
RATE_LIMIT="300K"
mkdir ../$DOWNLOAD_PATH
BASE_COMMAND="screen wget --continue --directory-prefix=../$DOWNLOAD_PATH --tries=2 --input-file=$DOWNLOAD_PATH"
${BASE_COMMAND} --limit-rate=${RATE_LIMIT}
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves it. I really should learn more about bash scripting, so that I wont repeat stupid mistakes like this one...